# .NET Application version compatibility between .NET 6 Desktop Runtime versions

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, sdk

I am working on a Visual Studio Solution with an C# application project (WPF). This project targets net6.0-window framework. My goal is to be compatible with every .NET6 Desktop Runtime Environment version.

When running the executable on another machine the .NET 6 Desktop Runtime Environment in version 6.0.8 must be installed. But when the machine has already installed a newer Version (currently 6.0.12) the executable won't start and a window appears: "You must install or update .NET to run this application [...] version 6.0.8".

How can I configure the .NET project to allow also later versions of the .NET 6 Desktop Runtime Environment?

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/25220

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can try this [method](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/7176) to fix it.

```
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFrameworkVersion)' == '6.0'">
  <FrameworkReference
          Update="Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App;Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.WPF;Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.WindowsForms"
          TargetingPackVersion="6.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Update:

This issue is left over from previous versions, updating to the latest version can fix the problem.

The same problem can try to update to .Net 7.0 and then fall back to 6.0.x, this will fix the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I tried to add this lines but I do not see any effects with or.However, after I update to .NET 7.0 everything seems fine and the executable runs with different 7.0.x versions. Upgrading back to 6.0.x has also fixed the problem and I cannot reproduce this issue. Weird...